# How to get text from span in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to get text All New Products and Launches i am trying this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2/span")).getText();
```

but it is printing Folder

```
<h2 class="iselmf-h2-icon">
<span>Folder:</span>
All New Products and Launches
</h2>
```

Comment: driver.findElement() will return another webelement, from that element you could simply make another query to find by tag name (in this case, span).

Comment: remove /span from your xpath

Answer (score 1):

The text is in the `<h2>` tag, not the `<span>` tag. Try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the HTML tags

```
<span>Folder:</span>
```

The /span indicates that this is the end of the span, so if you're using the span as the identifier then it will only return folder.

The parent element of the span is the h2 tag. So to get everything between h2 and /h2 tags you need to do this -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2")).getText();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2/span")).getText(); This snippet will do the same thing, it will retrieve the text from span. Looks like you wanted to say driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2")).getText();

Comment: Correct, apologies and thanks for the correction! Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this,

1) `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2")).getText();`

2) Get the text from both and then concatenate it, something like

```
String firstblock = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2")).getText();
String secondblock = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2/span")).getText(); 
String finaltext= firstblock+secondblock;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite similar issue when getting the text from `span` attribute. The solution was to use `.getAttribute("value")` like this:

```js
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iselmf-folder-detail']/h2/span")).getAttribute("value");

**String org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getAttribute(String name)**
```